# Incluir un html dentro de otro usando Django

Tags: html, django

Juro que vi esto en alguna parte, pero no recuerdo donde. Quiero incluir un codigo frecuente dentro de varias paginas de html, pero no en todas, y seria util poder importar codigo de otro archivo igual q se puede heredar de otro html.
Alguien sabe como hacerlo con Django? No quiero usar rel=import si hay otra manera.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para incluir un html dentro de otro puedes usar el tag include.

Ejemplo:

```
{% include 'miapp/templates/seccion.html' %}
```

Si necesitas pasarle algún objeto, parte del contexto, etc seria de esta manera:

```
{% include 'include 'miapp/templates/seccion.html' with ejemplo=object %}
```

y dentro de este template ya podias usar

```
<div>
    {{ ejemplo }}
</div>
```